# Can ssh accept an encrypted password?

Tags: c++, c, ssh, openssh

I'm designing an app recently. For some reasons I can not use the ssh-key to connect to the remote server, so I wonder whether I could just pass an encrypted password to ssh, maybe just by imitating the way ssh does to encrypt my row password.

Comment: When I need to do something like this, I use ssh in the mode where it uses public/private keys, and not passwords.

Comment: You obviously studied the SSH docs, so which part concerning your doubts is unclear? What have you learnt already? What would the expected behaviour be even? What is the relation ot C++? And what about C? Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Comment: Looks like the password is sent in plain text so you can't do that https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4252#page-10

Comment: Look at `libcrypto`, you could find some help and C/C++ examples here [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption)